# How does one plot matplotlib markers with unique string values without using a for loop?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, markers

I have a Pandas Dataframe with about 2500 rows (and a new one added each weekday) that graphs a time series data of values with a single value as content. It's formatted in the way that it comes from the yfinance like this:

```
            Adj Close
Date
2020-XX-XX  250.000000
2020-XX-XX  251.000000
```

I have a graph done using `plot` but it's difficult for me to see the values and how they change relative to each other. Using the other methods from previous questions using `scatter` and a `TextPath` [(the top two answers in this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285163/clean-way-to-use-words-as-markers-in-matplotlib-and-make-font-size-and-color). Each of these use a for-loop and it takes a long time for it to run through each of the ~2500 rows. After it takes the time to plot each marker, the graph is perilously slow because I've just added ~2500 new unique markers to the graph - a problem I don't encounter with other calls of `scatter`. Maybe this is the nature of this strategy though.

How do you plot matplotlib markers with unique string values without using a for loop?

---

My approach at this point has been trying to use this line to accomplish this with one call of `.scatter()` like this:

```
plt.scatter(SMA3_1.index,SMA3_1["Adj Close"],marker="${}$".format( HELP ME HERE ),s=1000)
```

I have tried all I can think and find to fill in this spot but I'm a total loss.

Comment: Matplotlib does not allow to use specify different markers in single call of `scatter`, so looping will be your only possibility.

Comment: That's what it seems like, is there a different method (or method() ) that would be better?